# Override table prefix for a model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Hello I've in config/database.php a prefix (mysql) like this:

```
     'prefix' => 'myprefix_',
```

But I need, only for one model, to use a different prefix like:

```
     protected $table = 'otherprefix_mytable';
```

In this way laravel looking for "myprefix_otherprefix_mytable".

Any help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your `app/config/database.php` make 2 different connections like

```
'connections' => array(

        # first prefix
        'mysql1' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => 'prefix1',
        ),

        # second prefix
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'host1',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => 'prefix2',
        ),
    ),
```

And then later in model you can use different connection

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {    
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';    
}
```

For more help check [this](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections)

Comment: How this affects relationships using different prefixes? Although it is the same database, it is using a different connection.

Answer (score 4):

Default table prefix can be overriding in laravel model as following example:

---

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
    $collection = Config::get('database');
    $collection['connections']['mysql']['prefix'] = 'consultancy_';
    Config::set('database',$collection);
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 9 it would be:
`public function __construct(array $attributes = array()) {
        $this->getConnection()->setTablePrefix('me_prefix');
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }`

Comment: yes and this works in Laravel 8 too !